# Build failing when deploying to netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify, tailwind-in-js

Code builds without any errors or warnings in my local machine and runs with no problems at all. This is my first webpage, and I just cannot get it to deploy. I have been stuck in this step for a few days now and I am getting so tired looking at it. If anyone has an idea of that is going on I would really appreciate it. I am running MAC OS and VS CODE

```
2:10:21 PM: ​
2:10:21 PM: $ yarn build
2:10:22 PM: yarn run v1.22.19
2:10:22 PM: $ next build
2:10:22 PM: warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
2:10:22 PM: info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
2:10:24 PM: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
2:10:26 PM: Failed to compile.
2:10:26 PM: 
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/santiagoramirez/landing_githubpages/public/hhh.png' in '/opt/build/repo/pages/components'
2:10:26 PM: Import trace for requested module:
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/santiagoramirez/landing_githubpages/public/img100.png' in '/opt/build/repo/pages/components'
2:10:26 PM: Import trace for requested module:
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/santiagoramirez/landing_githubpages/public/img9.jpg' in '/opt/build/repo/pages/components'
2:10:26 PM: Import trace for requested module:
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/santiagoramirez/landing_githubpages/public/img15.png' in '/opt/build/repo/pages/components'
2:10:26 PM: Import trace for requested module:
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/santiagoramirez/landing_githubpages/public/img11.webp' in '/opt/build/repo/pages/components'
2:10:26 PM: Import trace for requested module:
2:10:26 PM: ./pages/components/Instagram.jsx
2:10:26 PM: > Build failed because of webpack errors
2:10:26 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1. (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
2:10:26 PM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2:10:26 PM: ​
2:10:26 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:10:26 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
2:10:26 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:10:26 PM: ​
2:10:26 PM:   Error message
2:10:26 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: yarn build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
2:10:26 PM: ​
2:10:26 PM:   Error location
2:10:26 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
2:10:26 PM:   yarn build
2:10:26 PM: ​
2:10:26 PM:   Resolved config
2:10:26 PM:   build:
2:10:26 PM:     command: yarn build
2:10:26 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
2:10:26 PM:     environment:
2:10:26 PM:       - NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET
2:10:26 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/.next
2:10:26 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
2:10:26 PM:   plugins:
2:10:26 PM:     - inputs: {}
2:10:26 PM:       origin: ui
2:10:26 PM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
2:10:27 PM: Caching artifacts
2:10:27 PM: Started saving node modules
2:10:27 PM: Finished saving node modules
2:10:27 PM: Started saving build plugins
2:10:27 PM: Finished saving build plugins
2:10:27 PM: Started saving yarn cache
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving yarn cache
2:10:29 PM: Started saving pip cache
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving pip cache
2:10:29 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
2:10:29 PM: Started saving go dependencies
2:10:29 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
2:10:31 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:10:31 PM: Creating deploy upload records
2:10:31 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:10:31 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
2:10:31 PM: Finished processing build request in 38.844689685s
```

Comment: Im just guessing, but it seems like you have imported the photos you use in the react app from your local machine, instead of adding the photos into the React project.

You should move all photos into something like /src/assets/ and import photos from there into your components

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.